# Test of handedness

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, cross-product

I'm reading a book on linear algebra, where the author gives a method to test the handedness or chirality of a given set of 3 basis vectors.

> if $(v1 \times v2) \cdot v3 > 0$ then it's right-handed, while if it's less than $0$, it's left handed.

What beats me is that numbers are just numbers, left or right handedness of a system depends on the viewer and how he interprets the given data.

Taking the canonical basis vectors $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$, in both left and right handed systems $i \times j = k$, thereby $k \cdot k = \lVert k\rVert ^2 > 0$ (always), then how does this test hold true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Orientation (handedness) is not about a set of vectors, it is about an ordered list of vectors. That is, a certain ordering, $(i,j,k)$ is agreed to as right handed. Then $(j,i,k)$ is left handed. This may or may not agree with some notion you have from physics, hard to predict.

A smooth manifold is orientable...never mind.

Comment: Could you please add an example explaining in what case the condition would be false? Sorry if this is inappropriate or what I'm asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: @legends2k, $j \times i = -k,$ so $(j \times i) \cdot k < 0,$ so the ordered basis $(j,i,k)$ has the opposite orientation compared with $(i,j,k).$ Looking at your question again, I do not know what you mean by a "left or right handed system," so I would say the use of the word "system" and the phrase "depends on the viewer" indicate thinking from some view of this that is not that of linear algebra or differential geometry texts. Perhaps computer graphics? There is no viewer in a vector space.

Comment: Computer graphics it is :( However, I meant the interpreter or the person who, say, plots the values or draws the vector in a reference frame (of his/her own choice) as opposed to a hypothetical viwer _in_ the space. For him how would this test help prove what he draw is left or right handed?

Comment: The concept of induced orientation is probably what you want. If I stand outside a bank looking at a big glass window, I can draw a curved quarter-circle arrow with a marker on the window, indicating clockwise rotation by the location of the arrowhead. If I now walk inside the bank and look back out at the same window, the arrow seems now to indicate counterclockwise rotation.

Comment: @legends2k, forgot to put at sign on previous

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an assumption behind your quoted statement, that is, the basis vectors used to express $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are in a right-handed coordinate system.  Then everything makes more sense.  So when you define arbitrarily three vectors (e.g. $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$),  $(v_1\times v_2)\cdot v_3$ will tell if the three vectors have the "same" handedness or the "opposite" handedness as compared to the handedness of the basis vectors.

For example, if you define $v_1=[1,0,0]$, $v_2=[0,1,0]$ and $v_3=[0,0,1]$, which are basically equivalent to the basis vectors, the handedness test $(v_1\times v_2)\cdot v_3$ is positive as expected since your basis vectors are by assumption in a right-handed coordinate system.

And when your twist the above example a bit by defining $v_1=[1,0,0]$, $v_2=[0,1,0]$ and $v_3=[0,0,-1]$, the handedness test $(v_1\times v_2)\cdot v_3$ is negative.

So your quoted statement is better written as:

> **Given that v1, v2 and v3 are defined in a right-handed coordinate system**, if (v1×v2)⋅v3>0 then it's right-handed, while if it's less than 0, it's left handed.